# When using git, every time I need to fix a bug, should I create a new branch from master ,or try to re-use a branch like "my_fix_bug" repeatly?

Tags: git

After read this:
[What are some examples of commonly used practices for naming git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273695/git-branch-naming-best-practices)
I think I should create new branch from master, naming it as "fix_[issue number]" for it's easier to know what is the branch for by branch name.

But my colleague think it's better to keep branch counts low, and he doesn't think branch name is a issue.

Am I using git branch wrong, or is it okay to use git branch in different ways?

Comment: Note if you delete the branch after merging it (which you typically would do), it doesn't matter if you reuse the same name. No one knows or cares what the previously used branch names were once it's merged and deleted. So, name the branch whatever makes sense right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget that the "number of branches" isn't absolute in a *distributed* version control system like Git.

Your *local* repo can use as many branches at it needs.
And yet:

- you can push only a *limited* number of it.
- you [can push a local branch under a *different* name on a remote repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740047/6309)

For other rules and suggestions: "[Too many live branches in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14483705/6309)".